# unslider is not working with mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache, unslider, jive

I am currently working with a client that is using a jive platform which only lets me input code into a html widget. I am trying to grab images from rss feed and input in a slider.

I am currently using mustache to grab the feed and create the template. That part I got to work.

and then render the images inside the slider (which is inside an ul)
that works too.

the problem is that the slider works sometimes and sometimes doesn't. it shows it is a slider but doesnt see the slides in the navigation. nothing gets appended in the ol element in the navigation. sometimes i see it working and when i reload the page, it stops. not sure what I am doing wrong.

here is the code - i replaced the rss url with something else. 
https://jsfiddle.net/cjpbgcn8/

js code

```
$(function(){
        var renderNews = function(income){
            var rendObj = []
            $.grep(income, function (n, i) {
                var subject     = $(n).find('title').text(),
                        description = $(n).find('description').text().replace(/\<\!--(.*?)--\>/gi,""),
                        descriptionTrunk = $(description).text().replace(/"/gi,'\\"'),
                        link        = $(n).find('link').text(),
                        image
                if (descriptionTrunk.length > window._config.truncateTo)
                    descriptionTrunk = descriptionTrunk.substring(0,window._config.truncateTo)+"..."
                if( $(description).find('img').length ){
                    image  = $(description).find('img').first().attr('src')
                }else{
                    image = window._config.defaultImage
                }

                rendObj.push({subject: subject, description: descriptionTrunk, link: link, image: image})
            });

            var news = {news: rendObj}

            var tmpl = $('#scr_main').html();
            var out = Mustache.render(tmpl, news);
            $('#content').html(out);
            // $('.image-wrapper').imagefill({target:'.image'});
            resizeMe();
        }


        var getNews = function(){
            return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: window._config.rss,
                    success: function(json) {
                        defer.resolve(json);
                    },
                    error: function(json) {
                        defer.reject(json);
                    }

                });
            }).promise();
        };

        getNews().always(function(res){
                    var response = $(res).find('item').slice(0,window._config.count);
                    if (response.length == 0){
                        //no results screen
                        var tmpl = $('#scr_nores').html();
                        var out = Mustache.render(tmpl);
                        $('#content').html(out);
                        resizeMe();
                    }

                    else if(response.length){
                        renderNews(response);
                    }

                    else{///error handling
                        var tmpl = $('#scr_error').html();
                        var out = Mustache.render(tmpl);
                        $('#content').html(out);
                        resizeMe();
                    }
                }
            );
        })
```

Comment: Maybe the js code for your slider has compatibility issues or it doesn't load correclty. Did you try use `setTimeout` for load your slider's settings?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Great idea! I did not try that yet. but i will let you know soon.